# Get every ID from every DIV with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a website which has multiple news articles in it's homepage. I have a function which removes letters if the news article contains more than 300 characters. A hyperlink "read more" will show up so the reader can read the full article. Once the reader clicks on Read More, he/she will be redirected to a link containing the article ID in it. For example: index.php?newsid=73

However, I need to give every DIV the ID of the ID of the news article. This isn't really much of a problem, the problem is: How would I get jQuery to get the ID of the div to give every hyperlink it's own URL?

My current code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    var myDiv = $('.content');
    var abc = $(this).closest(".content").attr("id");
        //var myDiv = $('.content').attr('class');
        //var myDiv = $('#content');
        //myDiv.html(myDiv.text().substring(0,300) + '<a href="#">Read more</a>');
    })(jQuery);
```

I commented a couple of lines just to test it. My code obviously doesn't work and I am kinda lost. This is how I give every div it's own ID:

```
echo "<div class='content' id='" .$myrow['id'] ."'>" .$myrow['content']. "</div>";
```

Comment: So what HTML do you start with, and what do you want to end up with? And, incidentally, this question sounds like you'll end up with two elements sharing the same `id`, which is invalid under HTML and difficult to work with in JavaScript.

Comment: $(this) does not really make sense in your code.  Look into using the jQuery each method $('.content').each(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `each` loop  ?

```
$(function(){
   $('.content').each(function(){
      var _this=$(this);
      // use _this now to get each items/It's internal properties /items
      var textContent=_this.text();
      //Do your substring function here and set the text back to the item
      _this.text("Put your updated text here");
   });
});
```

Comment: If he wants the `id` why would you use a jQuery object, and not just `this.id` (as opposed to the implicit `_this.prop('id')` or `_this.attr('id')`?

Comment: He may need the jQuery object to reset the value after substring functionality

Comment: It works exactly like I wanted to. Thank you. However, this kind of glitches my scrollbar. The scrollbar still behaves like the text didn't shorten. Could this have to do with my custom scrollbar?

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery's [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function

```
var arr = $('.content').map(function (i) {
    return this.id;
});
```

The resulting array `arr` will contain the ids.